# Why continuously compounded interest a standard in finance?

Tags: finance, interest, compounding

Why is the "continuously compounded interest" the standard in finance? Many finance textbooks use the formula e^rt without justification.

The assumption that the interest frequency is approaching infinity, it is very unrealistic but how did it become a standard in finance?

Comment: Because it is easy and convenient to manipulate mathematically, and because any non-continuously compounded return can be turned into a continuously compounded one.

Comment: @rubikscube09 is there any toy example to back up your answer?

Comment: Simple interest at $r$ per year is equivalent to continuously compounded interest at $\ln 1+r$ per year. For example 5% simple is same as 4.879% continuous. (Take the exponential of 0.04879 to see why).

Comment: [Dupliacte](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/55944/54838) which  was in turn closed because it is a basic financial question. Reading it will "back" up how they are related though.

Comment: @Akdemy The post that you refer to was a question about the relationship between discrete and continuous interest. It is irrelevant to my question because mine is asking why the continuously compounded interest became standard in finance.

Comment: @noob2 If these two things are equivalent, why many texts prefer the continuous one? Which mathematical property can be derived from the continuously compounded interests?

Comment: An exponential is easier to deal with mathematically than a product such as $R(n)=(1+r/n)^n$, and $\exp r$ is a good approximation to $R(n)$ because $\lim_nR(n)=\exp r$.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Duplicate](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/55944/54838) which  was in turn closed because it is a basic financial question. Reading it will "back" up how they are related: You asked rubikscube09 if he has a toy example to back up his answer. He answered that any non-continuously compounded return can be turned into a continuously compounded one:  $1+r_d = e^{r_c}$ shows this in the post I refer to (in this case use the natural logarithm to solve for $r_c$; or if the other way around, exponential as noob2 pointed out).

If you refer to a toy example for convenient manipulation; it's because you can use [calculus](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus#Differential_calculus).

Edit: A [differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_and_continuity) must be continuous.

Comment: Can you also briefly talk about why it should be continuous variable, rather than discrete numbers, to apply calculus on? In retrospect, all the calculus exercises that I have dealt with, are based on continuous numbers. Why no calculus on discrete numbers?

Comment: Because calculus uses limits - and put rather simply, limits are most effective when used with the real number system (continuum)